Bilinear pairing question
Can I calculate below equation?
$e(g_1^{a}, g_2^{b}) / e(g_1^{a}, g_2^{b+c}) / e(g_1^{a}, g_2^{c}) = 1$
'/' means divide.
I think it works, but there is no evidence to prove it.

Assuming the multiplicative bilinearity, isn't it clear?

FYI, to have a good response from the community always include the source where you saw this. The context is essential to remove ambiguity for us. Some authors write in additive notation some prefer multiplicative notation though the group operation is not multiplicative. In a recent Question @poncho write an answer so you can see more clearly about this.

Thank you for your help!! There is no source for this, because I am just curious of that does this operation work!!
I am not good at math,but I feel your comment said it is correct!!

@park: are you asking whether it is an identity (that is, if it holds independent of what $a, b, c$ are)?  (Hint: no, it's not).  Or, are you asking how to test, given a specific $a, b, c$, whether this holds?

@poncho I want to ask if the result of the left-hand side expression is 1!

Or did you actually mean $e(g_1^{a}, g_2^{b}) / e(g_1^{a}, g_2^{b-c}) / e(g_1^{a}, g_2^{c}) = 1$ (note that the $b+c$ changed to $b-c$).  That happens to be an identity (that is, it is always true).

@poncho: Thanks!! But I don't know why can't I compute (1,+2)/(1,2) first!!

@ponch: Or if i want to compute I suggested, should I write a equation like a below?
(1,2)/ {(1,2+)/(1,2)} = 1
